# Evitar código repetitivo en clases muy similares con método factory

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Tengo estás clases **InputElement** que son bastante similares:

```
class BaseElement:
    def __init__(self, locator):
        self.locator = locator

    @staticmethod
    def webdriver_element(driver, locator, wait_time, explicit_wait):
        return callback_webdriver(driver, wait_time).until(explicit_wait(locator))


class InputElement(BaseElement):
    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        driver = obj.driver
        element = self.webdriver_element(
            driver, self.locator, 30, EC.element_to_be_clickable
        )
        element.send_keys(value)


class DelayedInputElement(BaseElement):
    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        driver = obj.driver
        time.sleep(3)
        element = self.webdriver_element(
             driver, self.locator, 30, EC.element_to_be_clickable
        )
        element.clear()
        element.send_keys(value)


class InputElementAndWaitTime(BaseElement):
    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        driver = obj.driver
        element = self.webdriver_element(
            driver, self.locator, 30, EC.element_to_be_clickable
        )
        element.clear()
        element.send_keys(value)
        time.sleep(4)
```

El problema es que son bastante similares y parece un código muy repetitivo, cual sería la forma para evitar esto? por lo que leí una opción es usar el método factory solo que no estoy seguro el como lograrlo

Answer (score 1):

Si bien el patrón factory es muy interesante, para resolver esto se puede usar una clasica abstracción utilizando atributos de clase para denotar aquellas que necesitan llamar `clear` antes de enviar el valor.

```py
class BaseElement:
    clear_before_send: bool = True

    def __init__(self, locator):
        self.locator = locator

    @staticmethod
    def webdriver_element(driver, locator, wait_time, explicit_wait):
        return callback_webdriver(driver, wait_time).until(explicit_wait(locator))

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        driver = obj.driver
        element = self.webdriver_element(
            driver, self.locator, 30, EC.element_to_be_clickable
        )
        if self.clear_before_send:
            element.clear()
        element.send_keys(value)


class InputElement(BaseElement):
    clear_before_send: bool = False

class DelayedInputElement(BaseElement):
    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        time.sleep(3)
        super(DelayedInputElement, self).__set__(obj, value)


class InputElementAndWaitTime(BaseElement):
    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        super(InputElementAndWaitTime, self).__set__(obj, value)
        time.sleep(4)
```

Notar que se logra el efecto del methodo `set` en la clase `DelayedInputElement` colocando el `time.sleep` antes de acceder a la propiedad `obj.driver` dado que, por lo general, acceder atributos no tiene *side-effects* que deban importar.

Comment: La sugerencia de tipo esta disponible desde python 3.5 y debes aclararlo. Tal vez el AP usa una versión posterior pero siempre es bueno detallarlo

Comment: Buen punto @Christian! Gracias por notarlo. ^^